# SSH session ( Python object ) kept through whole lifecycle of a playbook

Tags: python, ssh, ansible

I have a question about ansible and included python tasks, `SSH` connection in it. So the main thing I want is to have a global SSH session what I can reach from a python module generally ( during ansible playbook run )

Now I  have a python module which builds up an ssh connection to a host and puts commands (getting as a parameter from ansible) in the host , checks the commands , does some own logic based on the commands...  closes the connection.

My problem is every time I use this module as a task in ansible it must create the ssh connection again and again ( because I always lose the session after the python script is executed ).

It takes so much time to connect each time because I have several tasks.

What more could I see, ansible is able to build SSH session and connect to host through, but then I don't know how could I pass that session and make `SSHClient` python object from that, which I could use to write commands on that.

So the general question Is it somehow possible to have persistent `SSH` sessions during an ansible playbook run which are not closed each time and I can use from a python script(used as an ansible task)?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!!

Comment: By default Ansible tries to keep master ssh connection and mux subsequent connections into master one without any overhead.

Comment: Thank you Konstantin! So you are tellng if I make a connection in ansible that will be the master, and all other I am creating during run for the same host will be linked to the master? . On the other hand my question was rather a bit more specific. The question is if I have an ansible ssh connection defined,  can I use that connection somehow ( can I reach it / make paramiko SSH Client object from the connection ) in my python script ( used as an ansible task )?? I would need somehow to use that "master" conenction in my python script. How can I do that? Thank you!